# Get-ADComputer Cmdlet Not Working On Windows 2016 Server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

I am writing this because I am stuck on a problem involving running Get-ADComputer Cmdlet on a Windows Server 2016 system. The system is connected to an AD network, already has a pretty open firewall configuration set, and does not seem to have anything else noticeably odd going on with it.

The exact command I am trying to run is:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property *
```

The general output received is:

```
Get-ADComputer : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.
```

I have tried a pretty large set of troubleshooting such as going through firewall, ensuring AD is connected, trying to ensure the AD server is running ADWS, and etc.

I feel like I am not getting anywhere at all as this has been a problem for me for the past couple days. I am hoping someone more skilled with Windows and AD systems can provide me some feedback, sanity check, or any general comments.

My end goal is simply to dump the AD to list all computers, servers, etc within AD and currently the only system I have access to with AD is a Windows Server 2016 machine.

Thanks for your help,
Joe

Comment: 1. Please don't do `-properties *` - there's no need to drag back everything. You can get a lot of info from the standard response, including the DNS hostname. Do `-properties [propertyname]` if you need something else. 2. what happens if you use ADSI? `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()` should output some domain properties

Answer (score 1):

Is the system you are doing the query from joined to the domain? If not you need to specify the ADWS DC and authenticate. For example:

$cred = get-credential

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * -credential $cred -server adwsserver.local

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ran (Get-ADDomainController -ForceDiscover -Discover -Service ADWS), found the Domain Controller, and then ran the commands you listed. However, I still got the same error (Unable to contact the server). This again was ran on a Windows Server 2016 host. I assume if the firewall was the problem I would not have been able to execute the discovery command. I believe I found a good DC. So, basically I just do not know what else to try to get this to work. My only other thought at this point is to try and think of another method to dump the AD hosts. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the firewall logs to see if any requests are being blocked? The discovery is probably not using the same protocol and port as the query you are trying to run. ADWS uses port 9389 by default